# Unable to see the whole content of displayed  log as a result of tail option

Tags: linux

I am using Putty to log on to the Linux Server and see the logs .

I used the command `tail -f -n 1000 MyLog.log`

It started displaying the last 1000 lines , On to the displayed content  but i could the cursor to the whole displayed content , i could able to move only within the buffer content .

Please tell me is there any other option so that i could able to see the whole content (That is 1000 lines )

Thank you .

Where do i need to change the settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because of Putty, which has by default 200 lines of scrollback.
You can change this by going to `Putty - Window - Lines of scrollback`.

Comment: Hi , i have updated my question with the putty image , could you please let me know where can i find this Lines of scrollback Option ?? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Click on Window (not Appearance) and there your have the option lines of scroll...

Answer (score 1):

You can use pagers, **less** is more common!

Run like

```
tail -f -n REQD_LINE_NOS FILENAME | less
```